# mongodb c# sort by field in a list of entries

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have a collection like this (I removed fields that are not related to the question)

```
{
   _id:ObjectId('5dd7d946cd9c645f1cdc21ef'),
   Versions: [
      {
           "Barcode" : "200830001128132700636"
      },
       {
           "Barcode" : "200830001128132700637"
      }
   ]
},
{
   _id:ObjectId('5dd7d946cd9c645f1cdc21eg'),
   Versions: [
      {
           "Barcode" : "200830001128132700638"
      },
       {
           "Barcode" : "200830001128132700639"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to find the greatest (max) barcode in the whole collection.

I tried with a code like this:

```
var options = new FindOptions<Document>
        {
            Limit = 1,
            Sort = Builders<Document>.Sort.Descending(d => d.Versions.Select(v => v.BarCode).Aggregate((v1, v2) => string.Compare(v1, v2) > 0 ? v1 : v2))
        };
using var results = await _context.DocumentiItems.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<Document>.Empty, options);
```

But I get ArgumentNullException, I think it's unable to traslate the expression with the aggregate.

Can you suggest me a better approach?, if possible I want to avoid the use of BSON strings and use only labmda expressions.

The type of is DocumentiItems is `IMongoCollection<Document>`

Comment: how about something like:`_context.DocumentiItems.Max(item=>item.Versions.Max(version=>int32.Parse(version["Barcode"])));`

Comment: sorry IMongoCollection  doesn't have Max(), if there are no other solutions, I'll try your approach with LINQ to mongo

Comment: just use AsQueryable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be easily achieved with the `AsQueryable()` interface like so:

```cs
            var result = collection.AsQueryable()
                           .SelectMany(i => i.Versions)
                           .OrderByDescending(v => v.Barcode)
                           .Take(1)
                           .Single();
```

here's a test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Item : Entity
    {
        public Version[] Versions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Version
    {
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var result = DB.Queryable<Item>()
                           .SelectMany(i => i.Versions)
                           .OrderByDescending(v => v.Barcode)
                           .Take(1)
                           .Single();

            Console.WriteLine($"max barcode: {result.Barcode}");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like very much the AsQueryable of mongo, because MongoDriver usually it traslates the query in an efficient way. But this solution works and I can't find a better way to do this, so I am glad to accept your answer.

Comment: Another problem with linq, can I execute the query async without  wrapping into a Task.Run?

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti yes just import `using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;` and use the `.SingleAsync()` method

Comment: Thank you it works, now.
I have just another problem, the query takes 6 minutes, even if there is an index on Barcode. There are 75 millions of documents in the collection, find by barcode takes few milliseconds.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti can you confirm there is infact a descending index on the barcode and it has completed indexing all records? also, have you tried profiling the above query to check if the index is being utilized?

Comment: The index is ascending, but as Mongo documentantions says, for single fields the order doen't matter. I think the index it is not used because the generated query contains an unwind. Anyway wait six minutes for this operation is not a big deal, so I accept your solution.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti yeah you're right. apparantly index is only used for sort and match stages. i guess you'll have to change your schema and store the last/max barcode at the root level on every document if you want to cut down on the query time.